# Проблема с INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть интерфейс 1:

```
public interface IService 
{
   string TextString {get;set;}
}
```

Есть класс 1 реализющий это интерфес 1:

```
public class TextClass : IService, INotifyPropertyChanged  
{

   private string _textString ;
   public string TextString
   {
      get => _textString;
      set { _textString = value;
             OnPropertyChanged();    
          }
   }
   public TextClass { _textString = "XXXXX";}

  // Классическая реализация INotifyPropertyChanged
  // .....
}
```

Есть еще интерфес 2:

```
public interface IDataService<T> 
{
  T : TextClassLocal
}
```

Есть класс 2 реализующий интерфейс 2:

```
public class DataService :IDataService<TextClass> 
{
  private TextClass _textClassLocal = new TextClass()
  public TextClass : TextClassLocal 
  {
   get => _textClassLocal;
   set { _textClassLocal = value }
  }
}
```

Есть ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private _dataServise = new  DataService();
  private string _textMessage

  public string TextMessage 
  { 
    get => _dataService.TextClassLocal.TextString;
    set {
          _dataService.TextClassLocal.TextString = value;
          OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }


  // Классическая реализация INotifyPropertyChanged
  // .....

}
```

Усть View в котором :

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding TextMessage} />
```

Во View DataContext привязан и при запуске в TextBlock отображается правильное "XXXX"

А вот теперь самое интересное, во всяком случае для меня ;)

Если во ViewModel сделать операцию:
TextString = "UUUU"; 
то Text в TextBlock соотоветственно изменится на UUUU. Все ОК!

Однако если сделать напрямую:
_dataService.TextClassLocal.TextString = "UUUU"; 
то ни каких изменений не произойдет ;(
В чем может быть проблема? Как от нее избавиться?
В боевой реализации в классе TextClass реализуется Event который обновляет TextString и эти изменения ни как не отображаются в TextBlock

Answer (score 0):

Так в вашей вм TextString или TextMessage ? В коде одно, в описании другое... 
Если TextMessage, то ваш TextBlock слушает эту проперти (т.е. TM), при изменении которого инициируется событие PropertyChanged. А так вы меняете приватный филд, который никем не прослушивается. Поэтому и результата никакого

Answer (score 0):

Для того, что бы пользовательский интерфейс узнавал об изменении привязанных свойств WPF предоставляет интерфейс [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx), который путем вызова `PropertyChanged` сообщает клиенту что значение свойства изменилось.

В первом варианте

```
public string TextMessage 
{ 
    get => _dataService.TextClassLocal.TextString;
    set 
    {
         _dataService.TextClassLocal.TextString = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
    }
 }
```

когда вы напрямую изменяете значение свойства `TextMessage` вызов метода `OnPropertyChanged()` в сеттере свойства, как-раз таки и вызывает событие `PropertyChanged` что приводит к уведомлению пользовательского интерфейса и вы  можете видеть результат.

В случае вызова

```
_dataService.TextClassLocal.TextString = "новое значение";
```

уведомления о том, что значение изменилось не происходит, поэтому пользовательский интерфейс ничего не знает об изменении.

Для того что бы пользовательский интерфейс обновил значение свойства `TextMessage` после того как вы напрямую измените значение `_dataService.TextClassLocal.TextString` можно вызывать метод `OnPropertyChanged()` и в качестве параметра передать ему имя свойства, значение которого необходимо обновить.

```
_dataService.TextClassLocal.TextString = "новое значение";
OnPropertyChanged("TextMessage");
```